# Delete row when vlookup returns #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with this code below, but not sure how to delete row.

```
Sub DebitNote()

Do

'=VLOOKUP('Cost Gained'!$H2,SupplierSheetWithAddress!$A$1:$M$101,7,0)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP('Cost Gained'!RC8,SupplierSheetWithAddress!R1C1:R101C13,7,0)"


This starts in ("Cost Gained") from Column L,M,N,O,P,R
#N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
365 FOSSE WAY   SYSTON  UK  LE7 1NL         
SIR HENRY PARKES Rd CANLEY  COVENTRY    UK      CV5 6BN     
69-75 BOSTON MANOR ROAD BRENTFORD   UK  TW8 9JJ         
365 FOSSE WAY   SYSTON  UK  LE7 1NL         
PRAGSTR. 26-46  STUTTGART   GERMANY 70376           
69-75 BOSTON MANOR ROAD BRENTFORD   UK  TW8 9JJ         
#N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
33 WEST STREET  ALFORD-LINCOLNSHIRE UK  LN13 3DQ
```

I've got a loop on this to copy data over into a specific cell on another sheet so i dont want it to select #N/A and send it off as it wont be any good. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Or if i could skip the row that had #N/A in that would also help Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing A2 = #N/A ... if so why not use an If block around the code setting the formula? `if ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7) = "#N/A"` ???

Comment: Could you trim the parts that are not relevant to your problem? Create a simplified example if needed. [mcve]

Comment: You could filter out the error rows and copy the visible cells to the new sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrying on from my comment - just filter out the errors and copy the visible cells.

The example below shows the basics:

```
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Set up some data with a few #N/A errors
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
        .Range("A2:D20") = Rnd
        .Range("A6,A9,A12,A17").FormulaR1C1 = "=NA()"

        'Filter out the #N/A errors and copy the visible cells to a new sheet.
        With .Range("A1:D20")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have decided to make it easy and filtered out errors.